# startapp with manage.py to create app in another directory

Tags: python, django

My `Django` project structure is:

```
/proj
  /frontend
  /server
    /proj
    /app1
    /app2
  manage.py
```

How do I run `python manage.py startapp app_name` so that my newly created apps are within the `/server` directory? I tried running `django-admin.py startapp appname` within the `server` directory to create the app but I would end up with this error:

```
./manage.py runserver
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 177, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 72, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can **specify the path to `./server/appname` directory after `appname` as the `destination`**, i.e., where the Django app directory structure will be created.

From the [`startapp` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#startapp-app-label-destination):

```
startapp <app_label> [destination] # startapp command usage
```

> Creates a Django app directory structure for the given app name in the
> current directory **or the given destination.**

> If only the app name is given, the app directory will be created in
> the current working directory.
>
> If the optional destination is provided, Django will use that existing
> directory rather than creating a new one

So, you can specify the path to your `./server/appname` directory as the `destination` value.

```
django-admin.py startapp appname [destination] # Specify destination
```

**What do you need to do?**

**1.** You need to first create a directory, `appname`, inside `/server`.

```
mkdir ./server/appname # Create a directory from the root level
```

**2.** Then, run the `startapp` command to create the app.

```
django-admin.py startapp appname ./server/appname
```

Comment: This is because you are creating your app in a directory where there was one already or simply there were files with same names that are generated by `startapp`.

Comment: @Ivan does this mean that everytime I have to remove these files?

Comment: Well, yes. If you have an app in that directory already, what would overwriting achieve? Create it in an empty directory, or, if for some reason you want to overwrite them, just create them somewhere else and copy.

Comment: @Liondancer You need to create an `appname` directory first in `/server` and then run the `startapp` command. Check the edit.

Comment: @Ivan Here is the project structure: http://dpaste.com/3YM65DS

If I want to create my app within `server` But there are errors because `__init__.py`  is already in `server`. `app1` and `app2` have not been created yet. Which is what I am trying to achieve. But I get the file existing errors

Comment: This is because it trying to create the `appname` app inside `/server` instead of `/server/appname`. Now, inside `/server`, there are already app files present so the conflict occurs. Create the `appname` directory inside `/server` and then run `django-admin.py startapp appname ./server/appname` from the project root level.

Comment: @RahulGupta I tried your suggestion but I am getting this error now: http://dpaste.com/15TT9QA

Comment: @Liondancer Check out this Django link to configure the settings. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings

Comment: In [Django 2.1] the step 2 will return an error like ' appname conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.' Don't know why. So, I just omit the step 1 and startapp in the Project Root, then move it to the right directory, it works.

Answer (score 18):

I always have my app in an internal folder (the same that Django creates, with the name of the project) following the design of Two Scoops of Django that is similar to what you want to do. When you want to create a new app, you can use, as the previous answer says,

```
python ../manage.py startapp my_new_app
```

from within the folder in which you want to create the app. Another thing, even easier that is what I do, is that you can run

```
django-admin startapp my_new_app
```

from this inner folder, of apps and it will work.

Comment: This is much easier than the above solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you are already in the `server` directory, then you can run

```
python ../manage.py startapp appname
```

And `appname` will be created in the `server` directory instead of in the project root.

Answer (score 5):

> To Create a New App  in Django project.

**First:**

- Go to your folder using Terminal, where  you want to create app

**Second:**

- Type the below command in terminal,

```
django-admin startapp <new_app_name>
```

Now, you can check, new app created with the given name.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found is to go inside the `server` folder and create an `__init__.py` file:

```
touch __init__.py
```

Then, create any app you want:

```
django-admin startapp {{APP NAME}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you started the project using *cookiecutter-django*, then steps are given in the link below.

The difference from the accepted answer and other answers I see here is that you need to change the name of the app in *apps.py* as an extra step.

*[New apps created are located in the project root, not inside the project slug #1725](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1725#issuecomment-407493176)*

To copy paste that here:

1. create the <name-of-the-app> app with `python manage.py startapp`
2. move <name-of-the-app> directory to the <project_slug> directory
3. edit <project_slug>/<name-of-the-app>/apps.py and change name = "<name-of-the-app>" to name = "<project_slug>.<name-of-the-app>"
4. add "<project_slug>.<name-of-the-app>.apps.<NameOfTheAppConfigClass>", in your *LOCAL_APPS* in file *config/settings/base.py*

Here <project_slug> would be your "server" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path for the manage file. It works well for me, and here is an example to run from the destination folder:

```
python /home/user/project_name/manage.py startupapp app_name
```