# Cant start new app in django when I split settings.py file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

I splited my `settings.py` like this:

```py
# __init__.py
from .base import *  # noqa

try:
    from .local_settings import *  # noqa
except ImportError:
    message = 'ERROR: Unable to import local_settings. Make sure it exists.'
    raise ImportError(message)
```

```py
# base.py
"""
Django settings for app project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

# Add the apps folder to python path
os.sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

and:

```py
# local_settings.py
import os
from .base import BASE_DIR

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '670b9a538dfe8545f4eff723345da43211084a05f520a2d638'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'run/db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Every command works good except `python manage.py startapp myapp [or any other app name] ./apps/myapp`. Every time I run it command I get this error:

```
CommandError: 'myapp' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

I found it related with my code in `__init__.py` file. I mean if I comment all the codes, that error will be disappear. 
Why does it happend? How can I solve it?

[With Directory](https://ibb.co/1KjjSz5)

[Without Directory](https://ibb.co/ZTdxjbR)

Comment: As `myapp` name already exists seems your wildcard imports with `*` have overwritten some internal staff. What if you import contents of these modules explicitly by names instead `*`?

Comment: Hi @juggernaut, I tried it but I got that error too.

Comment: have you tried in the all affected files? `base.py` and `__init__.py`?

Comment: @juggernaut, yes, I tried in the all.

Answer (score 0):

As @juggernaut has stated. The error is happening when you use the character `*`, which imports everything and hence overwrites some internal.

When you run the command `python manage.py startapp myapp xxxx` The `myapp` section conflicts with an existing module and hence causes that error.

Try importing it manually instead of using `from .base import *  # noqa`. This way you only import the modules that you will need and would not lead to any errors.

Comment: Hi, but this command work well: `python manage.py startapp myapp # without any direction`

Comment: Yes, this command causes an error: `python manage.py startapp myapp ./apps/myapp`, but this one work well: `python manage.py startapp myapp`

Comment: Those commands are 2 different commands. The first is referring to the project dir (the one which django-admin.py creates). The second is where it executes your existing django app. You would typically only use the latter method unless you want to create a new django app (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243661/startapp-with-manage-py-to-create-app-in-another-directory) for more)

Comment: I has added 2 images to my question. Please see those.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019070/cannot-start-any-django-app) please. Any-one of it could be the solution

Comment: Not exactly, I now create a new app tricky. I go into the apps folder then use `python ../manage.py startapp myapp`. But I found out that reason.  It happened because I have to create app's folder before starting it; If I don't create it, django get me another error. I thing it's related with django implementation (or django bug).